# taphold not working with dyanmatically created listview in phonegap Android

Tags: jquery-mobile, android-listview, cordova-2.0.0

I have an listview which fect the data from the local database. And I want to add and taphold event on the list items so i uses taphold example from this site http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/5/23/Context-Menu-Example-with-jQuery-Mobile but when run this code on emulator its working fine but when  i tried to implement it into code which i'm usign its not working properly it giving an alert thats its in Taphold event but doesn't create a sampledialog box here the code which I am using:

```
function createlist(){
alert("I am in create list");
db.transaction(function(tx){
tx.executeSql(select_nameUserDetails,[],function(tx,results){
    $('#name').empty();
    alert("from list "+results.rows.length);
    if(results.rows.length>0)
        {
            for(var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++)
                {
                alert(i);
                $('#name').append('<li><p class="namelist" id="s'+i+'" onclick="selectname('+results.rows.item(i).id+')">'+results.rows.item(i).frist_name+'</p></li');
                 temp_id=results.rows.item(i).id;
                dataobj[temp_id]=results.rows.item(i).frist_name;
                alert(dataobj[temp_id]);
                }


        else{
        alert("No data present");
        }   
    });
$(document).on("taphold",".namelist",function(event){
    alert("I am in taphold event");
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).simpledialog2({
     mode:"blank",
     headerText:"Image Options",
     showModal:false,
     forceInput:true,
     headerClose:true,
     blankContent:"<ul data-role='listview'><li><a href=''>Edit</a></li><li><a href=''>Delete</a></li></ul>"
     });
});
});
}
```

here is the js and css files in using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="contactcss/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script><script src="js/index.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
```

here is the html code:

```
<div data-role="Content" >
<div data-role="listview" id="field">
    <ul class="Name" id="name" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b">

    </ul>
</div>
```

logcat Error i am getting:

```
07-13 17:29:33.145: D/CordovaLog(2696): TypeError: Result of expression 'o[0]' [undefined] is not an object.
07-13 17:29:33.145: E/Web Console(2696): TypeError: Result of expression 'o[0]' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js:4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When working with dynamically created content and jQuery Mobile you must use delegated event binding.

Instead of this:

```
$(".namelist").on("taphold",function(event){
```

bind it like this:

```
$(document).on("taphold",".namelist",function(event){
```

This solution don't care if **.namelist** exist or not. Tap event will be bound to document object and it will propagate to **.namelist** only when it become active in the DOM.

Comment: I tried this but still same problem it only show the alert box and after click on it doesn't show  dialog box.

Comment: Can you mail me your project and I will take a look at it?

Comment: sorry i cant mail you the code it againts or company policy but can you give me an example in which listview is created dynamically and when user longpress/taphold the list item i will create a popupmenu to select it would be a great help.